# Why does the for statement end at 2, not 4?

Tags: python

I wrote the code as below so that the for statement goes around 2 and 4. But I don't know why it only ends in 2.

```
def solution(n, lost, reserve):
    for i in lost:
        if i - 1 in reserve:
            reserve.remove(i - 1)  
            lost.remove(i) 
        elif i + 1 in reserve:
            reserve.remove(i + 1) 
            lost.remove(i) 
        else:
            continue
    answer = n - len(lost)
    print(answer)

solution(5, [2, 4], [1, 3, 5])
```

Which part of my code is the problem?

Comment: What does it mean *goes around 2 and 4*? Please add your expected output.

Comment: Don't modify an iterable while iterating over it.  `lost` is being edited.

Comment: I run the code, it print 4, what's the meaning only ends in 2

Comment: Can you provide the logic? Why do you remove the items from `reserve`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying a list while you're iterating over that same list will often cause you to unexpectedly "miss" items (because the iterating is happening by index, and rearranging the items underneath the iterator means it's no longer guaranteed to iterate over them in the original order, or in any order).  In general you should avoid this.

One solution is to build a list of the items to remove, and then remove them after the iteration is done:

```
def solution(n, lost, reserve):
    remove = []
    for i in lost:
        if i - 1 in reserve:
            reserve.remove(i - 1)  
        elif i + 1 in reserve:
            reserve.remove(i + 1) 
        else:
            continue
        remove.append(i)
    for i in remove:
        lost.remove(i)
    answer = n - len(lost)
    print(answer)
```

This assumes that it's important to remove items from `lost` because the caller expects them to be gone after calling `solution`.  If you're only removing them to be able to compute `answer` from `len(lost)`, it would be easier to just increment `answer` for each item you would otherwise remove from `lost`:

```
def solution(n, lost, reserve):
    answer = n - len(lost)
    for i in lost:
        if i - 1 in reserve:
            reserve.remove(i - 1)  
        elif i + 1 in reserve:
            reserve.remove(i + 1) 
        else:
            continue
        answer += 1
    print(answer)
```

Comment: I didn't know about that while using "for" statement until now, thank you so much!